# Context API not Reflecting changed state in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend, react-context, react-state-management

I am using context api global state 'items'. I push object to items array from 'Store component' & trying to access 'items' state from 'Cart' component but 'items' is not getting update when I try to access from 'Cart' component. Although changes are reflecting when I checked from 'Store' component. Below is the wireframe of the same app:

[image]

Here is code of all require files : https://codeshare.io/YLjL1M

Please help me with the correct possible solution.